# Date conversion problems

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm not understanding why my "hour" is coming out as 3.  I'm expecting 9.  Any insight to what I'm missing.

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate *currentTimeConvertedToHQTime = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];
NSLog(@"currentTimeConvertedToHQTime = %@", currentTimeConvertedToHQTime);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
int hour = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTimeConvertedToHQTime] intValue];
[dateFormatter release];
```

///logs

```
2012-08-20 08:55:13.874 QTGSalesTool[3532:707] currentTimeConvertedToHQTime = 2012-08-20 09:55:10 +0000
2012-08-20 08:55:13.878 QTGSalesTool[3532:707] hour = 3
```

Comment: Log what `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTimeConvertedToHQTime]` returns *before* extracting the `intValue` from it, just to see what's what...

Comment: check out your dateFormatter timezone also. There might be something there.

Comment: After logging what you suggested I get the same value, but prefixed by a one.  I also set the time zone to destinationTimeZone and still don't get the value that I'm expecting.

Comment: Do you want GMT in your sourceTimeZone? SourceGMTOffset is just going to be 0 the way you have it written.

Comment: Maybe I need another approach to what I'm trying to do.  I have user that can be in any timezone, but want to know if a user tries to do something in a between 9:00 - 5:00 central standard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` is probably not useful here.  Instead, constructing an `NSCalendar` object in the time zone you need, then get the `NSDateComponents` for the current time:

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];

// Create a calendar that is always in Central Standard Time, regardless of the user's locale.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];
// The components will be in CST.
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentDate];

NSLog(@"currentDate components = %@", components);
NSLog(@"currentDate hour = %ld", [components hour]);

// Test for 9:00am to 5:00pm range.
if (([components hour]>=9) && ([components hour]<=12+5))
{
    NSLog(@"CST is in business hours");
}
```

See the [NSCalendar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) for more of its powerful features.  For example, you can test for weekends.  Just make sure you request the units you need (`NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` in this case).

```
NSDateComponents *components =[calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"currentDate components = %@", components);
NSLog(@"currentDate weekday = %ld", [components weekday]);

// Test for Monday to Friday range.
if (([components weekday]>1) && ([components weekday]<7))
{
    NSLog(@"Working day");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Weekend");
}
```